# Laravel Belongs To Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

this should be quite simple but i don't know what wrong . i have the following migrations . 
create_players_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('club_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->double('price', 3, 2);
            $table->enum('position', ['goalkeeper','defender','Midfielder','Striker']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

create_clubs_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clubs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The relationship is straight forward as one player has one team (One to one) and one team can have many players (One to Many ) . The problem is i want to list all the players with their respective teams but somehow i end up with errors . This is my player model .

```
class Player extends Model
{
  public function club()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Club');
    }
}
```

And here is the controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $players=Player::find(1);
    echo $players->club()->location;
}
```

I get  this error

> ErrorException in TeamController.php line 15: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What is on line 15 of `TeamController.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is not really a database relation try to make you're relation like this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('club_id');
        $table->foreign('club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs');

        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->double('price', 3, 2);
        $table->enum('position', ['goalkeeper','defender','Midfielder','Striker']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: This will create a foreign key in the database but does not affect Laravel relations.

Comment: I know, I always think it good to give some feedback on his code. Like I said on the top of my answers, this is to make the correct database relation. I think the correct answer is that he has to check if the response of the relation is not null

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this :

```
$players=Player::with('club')->find(1);
echo $players->club->location;
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what you want to achieve? also i have updated the answer

Comment: Basically i want to join the two tables , so as the players array will have all information from the players table and clubs table , so you list a player with his respective team . I already achieved using join , but was wondering if relationships can achieve that...

Comment: yes you can do it!, `Player::with('club')->get(10);`, the returned list will have information about the players, also each player will have information about his club 
`

Answer (score 0):

**Player Model**

```
class Player extends Model
{
  public function club()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'club_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Player controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $players=Player::find(1);
    echo $players->club->location;
}
```

Comment: Ok , my bad . It only displays information from Club Model . I want to get all information from the Player and Team Model . I already achieved this using join , but can you achieve it with just relationships ?

Comment: @bobin56, read the docs, there is [`->with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: @BagusTesa , It's best approach ,  because the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. read the docs -> Eager Loading

Comment: @swaroopsuthar, it depends, if you wish to fetch only a single item, then yes, [lazy loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) using `$players->club()` is preferrable (notice the firggin `(` and `)` since `$players->club` will be null as it not loaded yet). but, if you fetch tons of `$players`, it is better to have eager loading - the `->with('rels')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `()` in `->club()`,

```
public function index()
{
    $players=Player::find(1);
    echo $players->club->location;
}
```

As the error says, it refers to the "BelongsTo" relationship. i.e. Here `->club()` returns the relationship object, not the club object. If you want to get the club object call as `$players->club->location;` .